# AFNetworking JSON array without value

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, afnetworking

I have a problem with AFNetworking to get JSON information from an API with the following format:

```
{
    "result": [
        [
            {
                "user": "test user",
                "password": "test password",
                "company": "test company"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

notice the {[[{}]]} (double square brackets).
But only one value "result".

I get the error:

```
ApiTest[83166:c07] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7136a30
ApiTest[83166:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7136a30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1da6012 0x123de7e 0x1e314bd 0x1d95bbc 0x1d9594e 0x3d60 0x3122 0x16909 0x179953f 0x17ab014 0x179b7d5 0x1d4caf5 0x1d4bf44 0x1d4be1b 0x21397e3 0x2139668 0x18565c 0x2a9d 0x29c5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

When i setup the file locally and just using a single set of square brackets "{[{}]}"  the JSON data is handled fine by my AFNetworking/JSON project code.

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "user": "test user",
            "password": "test password",
            "company": "test company"
        }
    ]
}
```

So without the double square bracket sets i can successfully get the "result" using:

```
self.results = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"result"];
```

If my project was javascript i would use something like:

```
var userId = data.result[0][0].user;
```

Does anyone know how the select my array correctly using objective C?
I spend a couple of days of investigating but i'm stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code that parses the JSON data and then tries to access the parsed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting an array inside another array, so you need to do

```
NSArray *array = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"result"];
if (array.count > 0)
    self.results = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```